# Use a className to define a canvas object instead of an ID..?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I am wanting to use this camvas object more than once but i am only able to get it to work when referring to a #ID.
Here is my code

```
function bubbleArrow() {
    var canvasId = 'triangleTwo',
      canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Draw triangle
    ctx.fillStyle="#f0f1f1";
    ctx.beginPath();
    // Draw a triangle location for each corner from x:y 100,110 -> 200,10 -> 300,110 (it will return to first point)
    ctx.moveTo(100,110);
    ctx.lineTo(100,150);
    ctx.lineTo(150,110);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

This works fine when i only need to use it once. i want to refer to my canvas by a className so to use it multiple times in my dom.

```
    function bubbleArrow() {
    var canvasName = $('.triangleTwo'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle="#f0f1f1";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(100,110);
    ctx.lineTo(100,150);
    ctx.lineTo(150,110);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Please any help on why it wont work when i target my canvas by a class name but will work when targeting it by an #id.
Thanks

Comment: When i try using the script that targets my canvas using class name it breaks my whole page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var canvases = document.getElementsByClassName('triangleTwo')
for (var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i ++) {
    var ctx = canvases[i].getContext('2d')
    // do stuff
}
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
$('.triangleTwo').each(function() {
    var ctx = this.getContext('2d')
    // stuff
})
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. Didn't realize i had to make several instances for the canvases[i].getContext('2d').